# Type of the Item property in F#

Tags: syntax, f#, interface, functional-programming

Consider the interface:

```
type IVector = 
    abstract Item : int -> float
```

Now, let us define the class:

```
type DenseVector(size : int) = 
    let mutable data = Array.zeroCreate size

    interface IVector with 
        member this.Item with get n = data.[n]
```

What about supply a method to mutate the n-th entry of the dense vector? Then, it would be nice to modify the above code as:

```
type DenseVector(size : int) = 
    let mutable data = Array.zeroCreate size

    interface IVector with 
        member this.Item with get n = data.[n]
                          and set n value = data.[n] <- value
```

However, I get the following error because of the signature of the abstract method `Item` in the `IVector` interface:

***No abstract property was found that corresponds to this override.***

So, what should be the signature of `Item` in `IVector`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type IVector =  
    abstract Item : int -> float with get, set
```

Comment: @Mauricio, yes it is.  That is, it is if you want to call the setter via the interface.  And if you don't, and only have the getter in the interface, then it's still illegal to uncomment the setter here: "public class V : IV { double IV.this[int x] { get { return 0.0; } /*set { }*/ } }" (recall that all interfaces in F# are explicit).

Comment: right, so in order to honor the original interface *and* provide a setter, you have to implement the property separately from the interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement DenseVector without changing the original interface while also providing a setter like this:

```
type IVector = 
    abstract Item: int -> float with get

type DenseVector(size : int) = 
    let data = Array.zeroCreate size
    interface IVector with 
        member this.Item with get i = data.[i]
    member this.Item 
        with get i = (this :> IVector).[i]
        and set i value = data.[i] <- value
```